# Thunderbird calendar doesn't save events

Tags: thunderbird, calendar

I have a hosted email service that I access via Thunderbird.

Currently, new events that I create in Thunderbird do not show in my calendar in Win11.

I create an event:"New event">enter details etc>"save and close" and there's nothing there.

I'm using v115.2.2

What I've tried:

- I've synced the calendar.
- I've removed and re-added the calendar, the issue persists.
- Attendees I add to the event also do not receive any notification.

When it kind of, not really works:

- Weird, when I set the event to "all day" it will appear in my calendar. If I set the time/duration to anything else, it does not appear. Editing an "all day" event to (for example) 12-1pm doesn't make it appear.
- When I create an event via the web interface of my email client's calendar, it appears in the Thunderbird calendar.
- When someone invites me to an event and I accept, it gets added to my calendar.